# Whitelisting IP in Openshift has no effect

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I updated the YAML in an existing route with the following:

```
metadata:
  annotations:
    haproxy.router.openshift.io/ip_whitelist: 192.168.1.10
```

However, the annotation has no effect. I am still able to call the service from other IP-adresses.

What am I missing?

Comment: See if any proxy or reverse proxy between 192.168.1.10 and router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift [route-specific annotations](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/routes.html#route-specific-annotations) will only work properly against the OpenShift HAProxy [router/ingress-controller](https://docs.okd.io/latest/install_config/router/default_haproxy_router.html) and OpenShift [route objects](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/networking/routes.html).

Third-party ingress-controllers will work on the OpenShift platform, but OpenShift specific features and functionalities will not always work with artifacts from the Kubernetes community.

Answer (score 0):

We are using a third-party Ingress that currently does not support annotation-based whitelists.